Differentiability along hyperplanes for rational functions
This is a follow up to my previous question.
Let $f\colon \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function that is rational and differentiable along all planes through $0$, that is, we assume:

There are polynomials $p,q$ of three real variables such that $f(x)=p(x)/q(x)$.
For all linear maps $\varphi\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^3$ the composition $f\circ \varphi$ is (totally) differentiable at $0\in \mathbb R^2$.

Question. Is $f$ necessarily (totally) differentiable at $0$?

As answer to my previous question (which did not require $f$ to be rational),  Saúl RM constructed a function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^3\backslash 0)\cap C(\mathbb R^3)$ with $f\circ \varphi\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2$)  for all $\varphi$, but which is not differentiable at $0$.
For homogeneous polynomials one should look for examples with $\deg(p)\ge \deg (q)+1$. If $\deg(p)<\deg(q)$, then $f$ will blow up at $0$ (and hence cannot be differentiable along planes) and for $\deg(p)=\deg(q)$ the function  $f$ would be $0$-homogeneous and thus continuity at zero would already imply that it is constant.
Instead of asking $f\circ \varphi$ to be (totally) differentiable, one could ask it to be a polynomial, which is to say that $q\circ \varphi$ divides $p\circ \varphi$ in the polynomial ring of $2$ variables. I have asked a related question here.


how is f defined on the zero set of q ?

I think such $f$ is at least Gateaux differentiable at the origin (that is, there exist a linear form $L$ such that for every $v\in\mathbb R^3$ there exists $\frac d{dt}f(tv)\big|_{t=0}=Lv$

I've included continuity of $f$ into the conditions, then being rational (as in 1) should be well-defined. What I was thinking of was essentially extensions of the 2-dimensional example $xy^2/(x^2+y^2)$, where both  polynomials are homogeneous of adjacent degrees and the only real zero of the denominator is at $0$.

If we knew that there exists at least  one  direction $v_0$ such that the  directional derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v_0}(x,y,z)$  are continuous at  the origin , one would conclude  by the  MVThm like in the  Total Differential Thm. But I don’t see why they should  be  even locally bounded at $(0,0,0)$;  not even in the simplest case ${q=0}=(0,0,0)$.
